# Write Conflict on azure backend

Tags: linked-tables

I am getting a Write Conflict Error I can't seem to get around. My database has all of the tables on Azure. The tables are all linked

I have a form that shows details about a specific course. I select the course by using a split form. On that form, I have a subform that shows the languages that course is being translated into.

Double-clicking on a specific field on the form displays another form with the details of that language's translation work.

The really puzzling issue is that I don't get the Write Conflict on all records. It occurs only on recently added translation records. I'm suspicious that there is something in those records that is causing the problem, but it isn't missing or invalid data.

I tried converting the table to a local table, and then I don't get any errors. I posted the problem to the MS Access community, and they sent me here.

Any ideas of how to fix it?

Thanks,
Merrikay